# file.entry phonegap doesn't work

Tags: android, file, cordova, base64

I'm trying to choose a file in the android device using the getPicture pluging, in its success callback i've this code:

```
 function showAlbumOnSuccess(imageURI){

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(entry){

                alert(decodeURI(entry.name)); //this show the file name

                entry.file(function(file){
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                      reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                        alert("read success");
                        console.log(evt.target.result);
                      };

                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                },function(error){
                     alert("error "+error); 
                });

   },function(error){
              alert("error : "+error);
          }); 

    }
```

when I run this code en mi app immediately show the

```
file.entry errorCallback (error code: [object : Object])
```

java.net.MalformedURLException: No installed handlers for this URL

I need to get a base64 code from the file selected.

Thank you.